# Prove that the radius of derived series $\sigma'$ is the same of $\sigma$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, proof-explanation, power-series

Let be $\sigma$ the power series given by the equation
$$
\sigma:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k
$$
so that we call radius convergence of $\sigma$ the quantity $\rho$ given by the equation
$$
\rho:=\sup\{x\in\Bbb R:\sigma(x)\text{ converges}\}
$$
So let be now $\sigma'$ the series obtained by $\sigma$ deriving each term, that is
$$
\sigma':=\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_kx^{k-1}
$$
so I'd like to understand better the following theorem proving that the radius of convergence of $\sigma$ is the same of $\sigma'$.

> > **Theorem**
> >
> > The radius of convergence of $\sigma$ is the same of $\sigma'$
> >
> > *Proof*. So let be $\rho$ and $\rho'$ the radius of convergence of $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ respectively. So fist of all we let to prove that if $\sigma$ converges at $x_0$ then $\sigma'$ converges for any $x$ such that $|x|<|x_0|$ so that $\rho\le\rho'$. So if the series $\sigma$ converges at $x_0$ then there exist $L>0$ such that
> > $$
> > |a_kx_0^k|\le L
> > $$
> > for all $k\in\Bbb N$ so that by the comparision test and by the inequality
> > $$
> > |k a_kx^{k-1}|=\frac{k|a_kx_0^k|}{|x_0|}\cdot\Biggl|\frac{x}{x_0}\Biggl|^{k-1}\le\frac{kL}{x_0}\cdot\Biggl|\frac{x}{x_0}\Biggl|^{k-1}
> > $$
> > we conclude that the series $\sigma'$ converges.
> >
> > Conversely we let to prove that if the series $\sigma'$ converges at $x_1$ then it converges at any $x$ such that $|x|<|x_1|$. So if the series $\sigma'$ converges at $x_1$ then then there exist $M>0$ such that
> > $$
> > |ka_kx_1^{k-1}|\le M
> > $$
> > for any $k\in\Bbb N$ so that by the comparison ratio and by the inequality
> > $$
> > |a_k x^k|=\frac{1}k|ka_kx^{k-1}|\cdot|x_1|\cdot\Biggl|\frac x {x_1}\Biggl|^k\le\frac{M|x_1|}k\cdot\Biggl|\frac x{x_1}\Biggl|^k
> > $$
> > we conclude that the series $\sigma$ converges.

So I do not understand why the implication
$$
\sigma\text{ converges at }x_0\Rightarrow\sigma'\text{ converges at any }x\,\text{such that }|x|<|x_0|
$$
implies that $\rho\le\rho'$ and anagously I do not understand also why the implication
$$
\sigma'\text{ converges at }x_1\Rightarrow\sigma\text{ converges at any }x\,\text{such that }|x|<|x_1|
$$
implies $\rho'\le\rho$.

So could someone explain this, please?

Comment: Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the implication

> $$\sigma\text{ converges at }x_0\Rightarrow\sigma'\text{ converges at any }x\text{ such that }|x|<|x_0|,$$

we see that
$$(-|x_0|, |x_0|) \subseteq \{x \in \Bbb{R} : \sigma' \text{ converges at } x\}$$
whenever $\sigma$ converges at $x_0$. Taking the supremum of both sides,
$$|x_0| \le \rho' \implies x_0 \le \rho'.$$
Note that $x_0$ is an arbitrary element of $\{x \in \Bbb{R} : \sigma \text{ converges at } x\}$, so we see that $\rho'$ is an upper bound of this set. The least upper bound (i.e. the supremum) of this set is $\rho$, so $\rho \le \rho'$.

The other implication follows analogously.

Comment: Okay, all clear now: question upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance!!!

Comment: You're welcome!